# How do I force a colorbox to always open with the same border size independent of browser size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, border, colorbox

I need a Colorbox to be customized: I want to force the colorbox image to open with exactly the height that is needed to have it a top-border of 70px and a bottom border of 50px, at a fixed centered position.

Also it would be nice to force it to rescale with browser - but thats another problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o.k. - so I made it with the following CSS:

```
#colorbox{
    top:0px !important;
}
#cboxWrapper{
    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-radius:none;
}

#cboxTopLeft, #cboxTopCenter,#cboxTopRight{
    height:70px;
    background-color:transparent;
    width:0;
}
#cboxMiddleLeft, #cboxMiddleRight{
    height:0;
    width:0;
}
#cboxContent{
    margin: 0 50px 22px 50px;
}

    #cboxLoadingOverlay,
    #cboxLoadingGraphic,
    /*#cboxTitle,*/
    #cboxCurrent,
    #cboxNext,
    #cboxPrevious,
    #cboxClose{ 
        visibility:hidden;
        display:none;
    }
```